# Hash.except() doesn't work with symbol keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a piece of code where this line:

```
user.attributes.except('created_at', 'created_by', 'updated_at', 'updated_by', 'id')
```

works (returns the hash with the keys passed as arguments removed from it), whereas changing it to:

```
user.attributes.except(:created_at, :created_by, :updated_at, :updated_by, :id)
```

doesn't (the returned hash still contains all the keys). How is this possible?

Comment: It may be because symbols don't have to be the same as strings, it's not allways equal

Comment: @Marcin AFAIK, symbols are never equal to strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because attributes returns a Hash with keys as string and not symbol.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes

and as said by others, String != Symbol.

```
puts :a == 'a'
# => false
```

Comment: I actually can't believe how stupid this was. For some reason, I believed Ruby hashes had some black magic inside that allowed you to use strings or hashes "representations" of the same key. I just discovered the only reason all my hashes worked is because I was always using symbols!

Comment: You can also convert any `Hash` to a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` and then you can access with both strings and symbols. Rails uses this is a lot (very user/developer friendly), and that is probably part of the confusion :)

Comment: Another part of the confusion is that Rails api docs, in the Hash#except section, give examples with _symbols_

Answer (score 7):

This happens because the keys in `user.attributes` are strings. You can symbolize them using `symbolize_keys` method and then use `except` with symbols like this.

```
user.attributes.symbolize_keys.except(:created_at, :created_by, :updated_at, :updated_by, :id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't hope this behavior in some case(such as treating http json response)

So I added refinements.

```
module HashUtil
  refine Hash do
    def eager_except(*args)
      proc = Proc.new do |key|
        case
          when key.is_a?(Symbol)
            key.to_s
          when key.is_a?(String)
            key.to_sym
          else
            nil
        end
      end
      eager_args = (args + args.map(&proc)).compact
      except(*eager_args)
    end
  end
end


using HashUtil
hash = { a: 'a', "b" => 'b' }
hash.eager_except('a', :b)
# => {}
```

※ Additional Info

after wrote above, I found other ways.

convert all keys to symbol with Hash#deep_symbolize_keys!

```
{"a" => "hoge"}.deep_symbolize_keys!.except(:a) # => {}
```

use ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

```
{"a" => "hoge"}.with_indifferent_access.except(:a) # => {}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 3 adds Hash#except to return a hash excluding the given keys and their values:

```
irb(main):001:0> user_details = { name: 'Akhil', age: 25, address: 'India', password: 'T:%g6R' }

irb(main):002:0> puts user_details.except(:password)
=> { name: 'Akhil', age: 25, address: 'India' }
```